# Problems with .NET 4.5 XmlSerializer, xsi:nillable attribute, and string values

Tags: c#, oracle, soap, xmlserializer

O Great Ones of StackOverflow, hear my plea:

I'm writing .NET 4.5 library code to talk to Oracle SalesCloud services, and I'm having problems with the SOAP requests that have null string values on the C# object.

The XSD for the attributes are specified as follows:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="OneOfTheStringProperties" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
```

Using the "Add Service Reference..." utility in VS2013 and writing a request where I'm updating something other than OneOfTheStringProperties, the output is

```
<OneOfTheStringProperties xsi:nil="true></OneOfTheStringProperties>
```

On the server end, this causes two problems.  First, since read-only properties are also specified this way, the server rejects the entire request.  Second, it means that I could be unintentionally blanking out values that I want to keep (unless I send every property back every time...inefficient and a pain to code.)

My Google-fu is weak on this one, and I don't want to dig into writing a custom XmlSerializer (and all the testing/edge cases that go along with it) unless it's the best route.

So far, the best I could find is to follow the the [Property]Specified pattern.  Doing this, then, for each string property available means that I have to add the following to the definition in Reference.cs

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool OneOfTheStringPropertiesSpecified 
{
    get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(OneOfTheStringProperties); }
    set { }
}
```

It's a LOT of typing, but it works, and the log traces for the SOAP messages are correct.

I'm hoping for advice on one of three avenues of approach:

1. A config switch, specific XmlSerializer override, or some other fix that will suppress the .NET 4.5 XmlSerializer output for null strings
2. Something like the same secret formula that will put out "proper" XML such as `<OneOfTheStringProperties xsi:nil="true" />`
3. A targeted tutorial to create an extension (or an existing VS2013 extension) that will allow me to right-click on a string property and insert the the following pattern:

   ```
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
   public bool [$StringProperty]Specified 
   {
       get { return !String.isNullOrEmpty([$StringProperty]); }
       set { }
   }
   ```

I'm also open to any other suggestions.  If it's a matter of just using the proper search terms (which, apparently, I'm not), that would be greatly appreciated, too.

In furtherance of this request, O Keepers of the Knowledge, I offer this [sacrificial goat](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3619#comic).

**Added For Clarification**

Just to make sure, I'm not looking for a one-click magic bullet.  As a developer, and especially one who works on a team where the underlying structure often changes due to requirements, I know that it takes a lot of work to keep things up.

What I am looking for, though, is a reasonable reduction in the workload every time I have to do a refresh on the structure (and for others, a simplified recipe to achieve the same thing.)  For example, using the *Specified means typing in approximately 165+ characters for the given example.  For a contract with 45 string fields, that means I would have to type over **7,425 characters each and every time the model changes--and that's for one service object!**  There are about 10-20 service objects up for grabs.

The right-click idea would reduce it down to 45 right-click-click operations...better.

A custom attribute put on the class would be even better, as it only would have to be done once per refresh.

Ideally, a runtime setting in app.config would be a one-and-done--doesn't matter how hard it is to implement the first time, since that goes into the library.

I think the true answer is somewhere better than almost 7500 characters/class and probably not as good as a simple app.config setting, but it's either out there or I believe it can be made.

Comment: I haven't given up on finding my own solution (and sharing it here if I do).  Digging deeper, it looks like implementing IXmlSerializer is not **the** answer...maybe just part of it.  The real answer might be IClientMessageFormatter (or associated).  I'll try to keep everyone posted.

Comment: If you're using the old Add Web Reference feature, I've had success in using SOAP extensions to modify the SOAP input and output arbitrarily - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Not using the "Add Web Reference...", but the "Add Service Reference...".  OTOH, the SOAP Extensions looks like it's right in the direction I'm going for.

Comment: Just to be clear, you automatically generated some c# classes, the code generator applied `[XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]` to a bunch of string properties, and you want to ignore this attribute programmatically rather than removing it manually from the generated code?

Comment: @dbc--pretty much correct, although it's not so much "ignore this attribute programmatically" as change the behavior of the generated SOAP message/XML output.

Comment: The equivalent of the SOAP extension in WCF is the IDispatchMessageFormatter interface, this article probably does the job of: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx - it includes an example of how to format WCF messages using Json.Net

Comment: You also mentioned putting the setting into configuration, the message formatter you write could use a fluent API style syntax to define ignored properties, e.g. message.Ignore(m => m.OneOfTheStringProperties) or you could load the list in from the app.config

Comment: @a-h:  That looks like it's shaping up to be a good long-term answer.  If I understand correctly, you create the IClientMessageFormatter (with associated `[CustomBehavior]` implementations) and add the `[]` markers to the relevant objects.  That about sums it up?

Comment: Sorry for the dead air, guys.  I've got two great answers, both of which directly address one of the avenues I was wanting to try, and both look like they are great approaches for others running into the same problem.  I'll try to verify their functionality and pick one.  (Wish I could split the bounty, or had enough credit to give to both...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to add a custom behaviour to the WCF client which can be used to inspect the message and skip the properties.

This is a combination of:

- https://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/iclientmessageinspector/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stcheng/archive/2009/02/21/wcf-how-to-inspect-and-modify-wcf-message-via-custom-messageinspector.aspx

Full Code:

```
void Main()
{
    var endpoint = new Uri("http://somewhere/");

    var behaviours = new List<IEndpointBehavior>()
    {
        new SkipConfiguredPropertiesBehaviour(),
    };

    var channel = Create<IRemoteService>(endpoint, GetBinding(endpoint), behaviours);
    channel.SendData(new Data()
    {
        SendThis = "This should appear in the HTTP request.",
        DoNotSendThis = "This should not appear in the HTTP request.",
    });
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRemoteService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int SendData(Data d);
}

public class Data
{
    public string SendThis { get; set; }
    public string DoNotSendThis { get; set; }
}

public class SkipConfiguredPropertiesBehaviour : IEndpointBehavior
{
   public void AddBindingParameters(
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
        ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new SkipConfiguredPropertiesInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
        EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}

public class SkipConfiguredPropertiesInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(
        ref Message reply, 
        object correlationState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received the following reply: '{0}'", reply.ToString());
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(
        ref Message request, 
        IClientChannel channel)
    {     
        Console.WriteLine("Was going to send the following request: '{0}'", request.ToString());

        request = TransformMessage(request);

        return null;
    }

    private Message TransformMessage(Message oldMessage)
    {
        Message newMessage = null;
        MessageBuffer msgbuf = oldMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        XPathNavigator nav = msgbuf.CreateNavigator();

        //load the old message into xmldocument
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using(var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
        {
            nav.WriteSubtree(xw);
            xw.Flush();
            xw.Close();
        }

        ms.Position = 0;
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(ms));

        //perform transformation
        var elementsToRemove = xdoc.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName.Equals("DoNotSendThis")).ToArray();

        foreach(var e in elementsToRemove)
        {
            e.Remove();
        }

        // have a cheeky read...
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        Console.WriteLine("We're really going to write out: " + xdoc.ToString());

        //create the new message           
        newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(xdoc.CreateReader(), int.MaxValue, oldMessage.Version);

        return newMessage;
    }    
}

 public static T Create<T>(Uri endpoint, Binding binding, List<IEndpointBehavior> behaviors = null)
{
    var factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding);

    if (behaviors != null)
    {
        behaviors.ForEach(factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add);
    }

    return factory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(endpoint));
}

public static BasicHttpBinding GetBinding(Uri uri)
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
    {
        MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288000, // 10MB
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 524288000,
        MaxBufferSize = 524288000,
        MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
        TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
        Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
        {
            Mode = uri.Scheme == "http" ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.None : BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
        }
    };

    return binding;
}
```

Here's a link to the LinqPad script: http://share.linqpad.net/kgg8st.linq

If you run it, the output will be something like:

```
Was going to send the following request: '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IRemoteService/SendData</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SendData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <d xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:DoNotSendThis>This should not appear in the HTTP request.</d4p1:DoNotSendThis>
        <d4p1:SendThis>This should appear in the HTTP request.</d4p1:SendThis>
      </d>
    </SendData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'
We're really going to write out: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action a:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">http://tempuri.org/IRemoteService/SendData</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SendData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <d xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:SendThis>This should appear in the HTTP request.</a:SendThis>
      </d>
    </SendData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Here's the output from Fiddler, proving that the HTTP message was actually modified: http://i.imgur.com/1G6xQRP.png

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the perfect solution but along the 45 right click line, you could use a [T4 Text Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate the XXXSpecified properties in a partial class declaration separated from the generated web service code.

It would then be a single right click -> run custom tool to regenerate the XXXSpecified code when the service reference is updated.

Here is an example template, which generates code for all string properties of classes in a given namespace:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)<Path to assembly containing service objects>" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#
    string serviceObjectNamespace = "<Namespace containing service objects>";
#>

namespace <#= serviceObjectNamespace #> {

<#
        foreach (Type type in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                       .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == serviceObjectNamespace)) {

        var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
        if (properties.Count() > 0) {
#>

    public partial class <#= type.Name #> {

    <#
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties) {
    #>

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool <#= prop.Name#>Specified 
        {
            get { return <#= prop.Name#> != null; }
            set { }
        }

    <#
        } 
    #>

    }

<#
    } }
#>

}
```

Comment: Very nice--I'm going to try to implement this today.  And the link is extremely helpful--the kind of customization I can do for industry-specific boilerplate code.  I'll let you know as soon as I have something.